# How to set the equivalent of Region on a ToolStripItem

Tags: .net, winforms, user-interface

Is there a way in Winforms to change the shape of a ToolStrip item.  If it were a panel, I could set the Region to my GraphicPath object.  But for ToolStripItem, I don't know how to do this, since it isn't derived from Control.
[alt text http://store.ezburn.com/images/productimages/toolstripbuttonshapes.jpg](http://store.ezburn.com/images/productimages/toolstripbuttonshapes.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create you own [ToolStripRenderer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstriprenderer.aspx), and paint buttons in your code. With such approach you can simulate any shape, and in general almost anything.

Then after custom renderer is complete, you will need to assign your renderer to toolstrip and thats it.

An [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/menus/CustomToolStripRenderer.aspx) describing writing custom renderers.

**Update:** You can also check [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/jfoscoding/pages/sample-tabstrip-app.aspx), it can be useful for your task.

Comment: Hi, Thanks.  I have this done already.  The shape of the button can be drawn differently, but on the toolstrip, it always takes up a rectangular area.  I'll edit above to provide current image.

Comment: Hi
Thanks for the second link, it is interesting.  I see how it could be done.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is possible, after seeing the second link in arbiter's post, but I will keep my solution.  With time being short because of deadlines, I've changed the type of control to a plain button.  Here I can set the region, and have been able to reproduce the required look by setting the region to what I call the chevron path.  The top two buttons are derived from Windows.Forms.Button with custom paint and region set.  The bottom two buttons are the toolstrip buttons with custom renderer and custom paint.

[alt text http://store.ezburn.com/images/productimages/toolstripbuttonshapes-final.jpg](http://store.ezburn.com/images/productimages/toolstripbuttonshapes-final.jpg)

I don't know if this will be helpful to anyone.  But here's the code I use to set the region:

```
    Private Sub setRegion()

        Dim r As Rectangle = ClientRectangle
        Me.Region = New Region(getChevronPath(r.X, r.Y, r.Width, r.Height))

    End Sub

 Private Function getChevronPath(ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single, _
       ByVal width As Single, ByVal height As Single) As GraphicsPath

        Dim w As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(X + width - ChevronHeight)
        Dim hh As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(height / 2)

        Dim gp As New GraphicsPath()
        'top
        gp.AddLine(X, Y, w, Y)
        'arrowtop, on the right
        gp.AddLine(w, Y, w + ChevronHeight, hh)
        'arrowbottom, on the right
        gp.AddLine(w + ChevronHeight, hh, w, Y + height)
        'bottom
        gp.AddLine(w, Y + height, X, Y + height)

        If EndButton Then
            'left
            gp.AddLine(X, Y + height, X, Y)
        Else
            'arrowbottom, on the left
            gp.AddLine(X, Y + height, ChevronHeight, hh)
            'arrowtop on the left
            gp.AddLine(ChevronHeight, hh, X, Y)
        End If

        gp.CloseFigure()

        Return gp
    End Function
```

Comment: This can be easily done with small controls overlapping (and without using regions). Both with buttons or toolstripitems. Of course small triangles on top and bottom of arrow will belong to upper button, but this is not big deal for most users.

Comment: Oh, I see that you already use overlapping. Anyway small toolstripbuttons overlapping can produce same visual appearance.

Comment: Hi
Same visual appearance - until the button is pushed and the overlap becomes plainly visible.   :-(